# Button click reloads the whole web page -Webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have a popUp dialog in my web application with Yes/No options, which will reload a specific DIV element in the webpage upon clicking "Yes". The issue is rather than doing a reload of that DIV element, webdriver does a whole page reload upon the click of "Yes" button.

Would you guys can think of any reason behind this behavior ?

selenium-java version : 2.33
Firefox version : 21.0

Comment: And if you click that button manually - what happens?

Comment: Manually it works as it is supposed to work.

@user1177636
Thanks for pointing out different browser issue. I tried with chromedriver and it works perfectly as it is supposed to work. Seems to be a FirefoxDriver issue.

Comment: I tried through a JS command to perform the click only to receive the same result.